# Set button on next page to focus like the button clicked by the user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering if there's someway to set focus to the same button or div clicked in the previous page, on the new page opened by the user. Currently I have a header that contains a top navigation bar that is the same on every page, but what I would like to do is when the user clicks one of the navigation button and goes to the next page, that navigation button stays highlighted (or on focus) in the next page. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Here is the current code for the navigation bar:

```css
div.scrollmenu {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.scrollmenu a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

div.scrollmenu a:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}

div.scrollmenu a:focus {
  background-color: #777;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollmenu">
  <a tabindex="1" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a tabindex="2" href="#news">News</a>
  <a tabindex="3" href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a tabindex="4" href="#about">About</a>
  <a tabindex="5" href="#support">Support</a>
  <a tabindex="6" href="#blog">Blog</a>
  <a tabindex="7" href="#tools">Tools</a>
  <a tabindex="8" href="#base">Base</a>
  <a tabindex="9" href="#custom">Custom</a>
  <a tabindex="10" href="#more">More</a>
  <a tabindex="11" href="#logo">Logo</a>
  <a tabindex="12" href="#friends">Friends</a>
  <a tabindex="13" href="#partners">Partners</a>
  <a tabindex="14" href="#people">People</a>
  <a tabindex="15" href="#work">Work</a>
</div>
```

The issue with this is that the page refreshes the header navigation when the user is redirected to the next page, so if the user clicks on one of the menu tabs, its hightlighted on the current page but then the user is navigated to the next page and its no longer highlighted or focused. Basically I want it so when the user clicks the navigation tab, it stays highlighted on the current page and the next page they are navigated to.

The use of javascript, jquery, or even just regular html and css is fine with me.

Any help is always appreciated

Comment: `Element.focus()`.

Comment: There are three ways to do it, You must either read the URL parameter in javascript, or handle in your backend, or use LocalStorage to store the current page info for user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way is to create an `active`class, that when you switch pages you get to update which links should be active or not, check out the below example

```js
// Code goes here

$(function(){
  
  //watch for the changes in the url and update nav respectively
   $(window).hashchange(function(){
     var hash = location.hash.replace( /^#/, '' );
     alert(hash+"-"+location.hash);
     
     //update our nav now
     updateNav(location.hash);
     
   });
  
  function updateNav(hash){
    $("[data-active]").each(function (index, item){
    
    // get the active class name
      var activeClass = $(this).attr("data-active");
      //remove it from each 
      $(this).removeClass(activeClass);
       
      // get the href
      var href =$(this).attr("href");
      
      //compare and update the class if the hash is same with the href
     if(href == hash){
       $(this).addClass(activeClass); 
     }
    });
  }
  
  
  
});
```

```css
.active {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 
    <nav>
      <a data-active="active"  href="#/home">Home</a>
      <a data-active="active" href="#/about">About</a>
      <a data-active="active" href="#/page2">Page 2</a>
    </nav>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-hashchange/1.3/jquery.ba-hashchange.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The most common approach is to add a class `active` based on the URL using Javascript/jQuery, or in your serverside code, then use that class to highlight the element in the header.